# Can you disable the activation email on login?

Tags: security, login

I have a demo org that is a enterprise partner account, specifically created and maintained for demos. I'd like to let people use this on their own but it's frustrating to have to figure out who just requested access and forward them the activation code or get their IP and approve it ahead of time. I just don't care about this level of security, it's too restrictive for what we are trying to do.

It used to be that you could disable the activation email by setting an IP range that covered the entire range of IPs. Salesforce no longer allows this (you get an error that the range is too large).

Is there any way to disable this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into each profile that should be globally accessible, and set the Login IP Range to 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255. Valid login ranges supersede trusted network access, so this will allow users with that profile to login from anywhere in the world without activation. See [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_loginrestrict.htm&language=en_US) where they discuss the implications of using login ranges, particularly as follows:

> ... Salesforce then checks whether the user’s profile has IP address restrictions. If IP address restrictions are defined for the user’s profile, any login from an undesignated IP address is denied, and any login from a specified IP address is allowed...

This occurs *before* network verification and therefore bypasses it.

Comment: does it bypasses or gets precedence over trusted network access?

Comment: Login IP restrictions bypasses trusted networks, because it has precedence. You might say the two terms are synonymous.

Comment: Update: @sfdcfox I believe we can no longer give ranges as vast as 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 not even up to 16.255.255.255
So I guess we will have to go with using the chrome extension only as the javascript customlink code also doesnt work any longer due to disabling of javascript on custom home components

Comment: @TheRecruit - You can't use ranges that vast in Setup > Network Access, but you can do so at the profile level (Login IP Ranges).